# What codecs are needed to be installed to support WordPress playback from local directory on a debian 8 vps

Tags: debian, video, vps

What codecs are needed to be installed to support WordPress video playback from local directory on a debian 8 vps?

Because I have vps debian 8, with WordPress running and easy video player installed and video added to WordPress using add from server plug-in, but no playback. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin's sparse documentation on https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-video-player/ does at no point mention server-side re-encoding. I suspect the videos to be transmitted as they are. For this reason, you need to encode them in a HTML5 compliant way **before** uploading them to the server. There are many ways to achieve this, personally I like to use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.something -c:a aac -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `-c:a aac` selects the AAC audio encoder with default quality.
- `-crf 23` sets the video quality. Use smaller values (e.g. 16) for better quality. ffmpeg automatically selects x264 for H.264 video in mp4.
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is needed for compatibility with browsers on MacOS and some Windows environments.
- `-movflags +faststart` allows playback of a partially transferred video.

Sources: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I did not install ffmpeg on my vps. What else should I install on my vps?

Comment: As  @Herrmann said: this plugin doesn't do server-side conversions. So: either you encode the video files _before_ uploading, or you search for another plugin.